# Index of list within dictionary using range() function

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, range

i have made a dictionary "bookshelf" with two keys, each key having a list of two elements.
i want to print out the contents of my dictionary "bookshelf" in key-value pairs, in sequence.
when i use the screenshot's code, i am getting a repetition. The code is reading my dictionary twice.
[image: Screenshot]

I tried moving the loops in and out of each other.
I tried changing the range to (0,1).

Comment: You are running it twice as you have the print level wrapped in the range level.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in `range` increments automaticlly you don't have to use `i = i + 1` unless you want to.

further you're iterating twice.

```py
bookshelf = {'name':['1', '2'], 'author': ["First", "Second"]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(len(bookshelf.get('name'))):
        print(bookshelf['name'][i])
        print(bookshelf['author'][i])
```

Comment: Can you please explain the if statement

Comment: It is only the [main](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following :

```
bookshelf={'A':['A1','A2'],'B':['B1','B2']}
for i in range(0,2):
    print(f"The name of the book is {bookshelf['A'][i]}, the name of the author is {bookshelf['B'][i]} ")
```

the key,value command was not needed for this problem.